# xcodeのviewcontrollerの見た目

Tags: xcode

アプリ作成の勉強をしている初心者です。

ViewControllerの上のバーと下のビュー部分に隙間があります。
書籍やウェブのスクリーションショットでは、そのような隙間は無いのですが、
なにか設定を知らない間にいじってしまったのでしょうか？

現在勉強してサンプルを作っているときには特に影響が見当たらないのですが、
気になるのでおしえて頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: hiromitsuさんの環境で動かした際のスクリーンショットを質問文に追記して頂くことは可能でしょうか？　質問の下の「編集」を押し、編集エディタの上の「画像」ボタンを押せば、画像を挿入することができます。

Answer (score 0):

もし、隙間というのが赤で示した部分のことを言っているのであれば、これは正常です。上のバーはツールバーなのでビューと区別するために少し隙間が空いています。

書籍やウェブのスクリーンショットと異なるということはおそらく、参考にしている書籍やウェブサイトがかなり古いものなのではないかと存じます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]